# How to expand and collapse with multiple interconnected node in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, topology

I have to ask this question again because I didn't find any helpful answer previously and I have spends many days to find the solution for the issue but not able to find the solution.

Here is what I want to achieve:

I am trying to use this link code and trying to add expand and collapse feature on parent node click.

What I am trying to achieve to hide and show the child node on parent node click.

I am using following code for this:

```js
 // http://blog.thomsonreuters.com/index.php/mobile-patent-suits-graphic-of-the-day/
    var links = [
      // {name: "Microsoft", children: "Amazon", type: "licensing"},
      // {name: "Microsoft", children: "HTC", type: "licensing"},
      {source: "Samsung", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Motorola", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Nokia", target: "Apple", type: "resolved"},
      {source: "HTC", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Kodak", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Microsoft", target: "Barnes & Noble", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Microsoft", target: "Foxconn", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Oracle", target: "Google", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Apple", target: "HTC", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Microsoft", target: "Inventec", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Samsung", target: "Kodak", type: "resolved"},
      {source: "LG", target: "Kodak", type: "resolved"},
      {source: "RIM", target: "Kodak", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Sony", target: "LG", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Kodak", target: "LG", type: "resolved"},
      {source: "Apple", target: "Nokia", type: "resolved"},
      {source: "Qualcomm", target: "Nokia", type: "resolved"},
      {source: "Apple", target: "Motorola", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Microsoft", target: "Motorola", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Motorola", target: "Microsoft", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Huawei", target: "ZTE", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Ericsson", target: "ZTE", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Kodak", target: "Samsung", type: "resolved"},
      {source: "Apple", target: "Samsung", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Kodak", target: "RIM", type: "suit"},
      {source: "Nokia", target: "Qualcomm", type: "suit"}
    ];
    
    var nodes = {};
    
    // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
    links.forEach(function(link) {
      link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
      link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
    });
    
    var width = 960,
        height = 500;
    
    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
        .links(links)
        .size([width, height])
        .linkDistance(60)
        .charge(-300)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();
    
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
    
    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
        .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
      .enter().append("marker")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 15)
        .attr("refY", -1.5)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 6)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
    
    var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
        .data(force.links())
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
        .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });
    
    var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
        .data(force.nodes())
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 6)
        .call(force.drag)
        .on('click', click);
    
    var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
        .data(force.nodes())
      .enter().append("text")
        .attr("x", 8)
        .attr("y", ".31em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
    
        function click(d) {
            console.log(d);
          
            
        }
    
    // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
    function tick() {
        
      path.attr("d", linkArc);
      circle.attr("transform", transform);
      text.attr("transform", transform);
    }
    
    function linkArc(d) {
      var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
          dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
          dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    }
    
    function transform(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }
```

```css
.link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #666;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    
    #licensing {
      fill: green;
    }
    
    .link.licensing {
      stroke: green;
    }
    
    .link.resolved {
      stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
    }
    
    circle {
      fill: #ccc;
      stroke: #333;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    
    text {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      pointer-events: none;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.13/d3.min.js"></script>
```

but in the click() function I am not getting it's child element name. So, how can I get child element names and hide and show them on parent node click.

Thanks

Comment: Can you define exactly what do you consider a children/parent relation ? Since you aren't representing trees, but graphs, this notion is a bit confusing here. Until you are more accurate about these definition about parent/children, here is a link of collpasible trees that could help you : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

Comment: @PierreCapo Sorry for the confusion, I don't want tree structure I have graph topology for which there will be multiple nodes connected to each other. For example please take this example: If "A" is main node and "B" and "C" connected to this and "B" is also connected to "c" and it will have multiple node hierarchy and one node can be connected to multiple nodes. The example you have provide it doesn't allow "analytics" to be connected with "display" and also it doesn't allow "display" node to connect with "flare" node. Please let me know if that make sense.

Comment: actually I want to achieve this => awesomescreenshot.com/image/3361839/… You can find this example => developer.cisco.com/site/neXt/discover/demo just go to Hierarchy NodeSet (issue) tab – test testing 1 hour ago